# jQuery on .submit check if login exists in DB and process the form

Tags: php, jquery, database, validation

I have this registration form for custom WP users where one of the required fields is LOGIN name.

The form is processed both ways, PHP and jQuery, and that works just fine.

What I would like to do is to check against the DB to see if given login name already exists.

Doesn't have to be on-the-fly, could be checked on submit, too, where I would run another PHP script, say 'checkUser.php' with simple code: select from DB given name and return true if exists (

I just don't really know if I should expand the existing code or find completely new approach.

**Any input is appreciated.**

*Functions.php:*

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts / styles
 */
public static function theme_enqueue_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('xxxx', esc_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri(XXXX) . '/assets/js/jqueryFile.js'), array( 'jquery' ), XXXX, true);
    wp_localize_script(
        'xxxx',
        'parajax',
        array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        )
    );
}
```

*Register.php*

```
<p>
<label for="login_name">Login *</label>
<input type="text" name="login_name" id="login_name" value="<?php
if (isset($_POST['login_name']) && ! empty($_POST['xx-widget-nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'xx-widget') ) {
  echo esc_html(sanitize_text_field(wp_unslash($_POST['login_name'])));
}?>" required>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login_name']) && esc_html(sanitize_text_field(wp_unslash($_POST['login_name']))) === '' ) {
    echo '<em class="f_req">' . esc_html__('This field is required', 'xxxx') . '.</em>';
}
?>
</p>
```

jQuery bit:

```
( function( $ ) {

    $( '#form' ).submit( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const form = $( this );
        const postData = form.serialize();

        $.ajax( {
            url: parajax.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: postData + '&action=ajax_form',
            success( resp ) {
                $( form ).fadeOut( 100, function() {
                    form.html( resp ).fadeIn();
                } );
            },
        } );
    } );

}( jQuery ) );
```

Comment: All I can see is a simple echo of the entered login-name , this would be the correct place to make a lookup

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. Simple "echo" to check the login value against the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Wordpress comes with the literarly function for that

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/username_exists/

in your register.php you would check for the posted name just like:

```
$uname_exists = username_exists($_POST['login_name']);
if(!$uname_exists){
  echo "username not existing yet";
}else{
  echo "username already existsing!";
}
```

Comment: I found that function, too :) The orginal idea had to kinda dropped but similar idea still is on and I used that function to check if the user exists or not. It is workin flawlessly :) Thank you!